# Using Pub/Sub on a public Cloud Run service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

According to the "[Authenticating service-to-service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service)" documentation for Cloud Run, to use [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/pubsub-push) and [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler) on a service, **unauthenticated access must be disabled** because they rely on HTTP calls because of the zero scaling capability of Cloud Run services.

My services allow internal and Load Balancer traffic and must be publicly available for frontend clients, but they also must be able to communicate with each other privately with Pub/Sub.

Is there a way to achieve this? It feels unnatural to create a separate private service just for using Pub/Sub.

Comment: Can you be clearer on what is calling what? Is cloud run which call PubSub or Cloud Scheduler API? Or the opposite, PubSub push subscription and Cloud Scheduler that call Cloud Run service?

Comment: I would like my Cloud Run services to be able to listen to Pub/Sub subscriptions. So Pub/Sub calling Cloud Run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a missing piece. You can't plug in your VPC PubSub push subscription and Cloud Scheduler (but also Cloud Task, Cloud Build, Workflows,...). I asked Google Cloud few months ago, and it should be fixed by a new network features, soon. At least in 2021!

So, in your case, if your Cloud Run service is accessible from the public internet through a Load Balancer, you can use this public endpoint to call the path that you want on your service and thus perform the process.

If your Cloud Run in only accessible from ingress=internal, you can't for now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
My services are publicly accessible, but I'd like to secure the Pub/Sub endpoints. I guess I'll attach my own tokens to the Pub/Sub messages for now.

Comment: Yes, you can't secure only one endpoint with IAM service. It's either the whole service or nothing. You can also use an API Gateway in front of your services to have a finer grain control on each path of your API.